# how to mock a class component by jest.mock in react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

here is my code structure

```
class Father extends Component {

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <Child {...someProps} ref={createRef()} />
      <SomeOthers {...someProps} />
    </div>)

  }
}

}
```

for some reason *(ok, it's [bit](http://bit.dev/). At present, it can not render child component automatically)*, I have to mock the child component in my test file.
so I do it like below

```
jest.mock('./Child', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => <element />
}));
```

cuz I have used ref, if I mock the child as a functional component, there will be a tips message telling me func component can not use ref.

Comment: Id you want to test only parent component then you can use shallow render it will not try to render child component.

Comment: depends on the renderer, maybe `enzyme` is not used